# Prolog Family Tree Blood Relations, Recursion?

Tags: recursion, prolog, family-tree, transitive-closure

I need a recursive function that finds all blood relatives in a family tree. But I honestly have no idea how to implement this in Prolog.

My current understanding for a solution, would be to search the current branch for a match and proceed to the next branch should there be no match.

For example:

```
           Peter
    Alf,            Bert
Sam,   Tom,   George,    Sally
```

To check if Tom and sam are related, we simply check the first branch by finding all siblings (checking the parent and checking all child elements).

This logic then applies as we iterate up the tree. For example, to see if Sally and Tom are related, first we check if they are siblings, if not then check the siblings of their parents and so on.

I do have predicates such as cousin, uncle etc, that can check things like this, but the problem is scalability. It seems ilogical to create predicates for great-great-grandfather, when I could just employ some sort of recursion to check if they are blood related.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

Here are some basic facts/ predicates to illustrate the angle I am approaching from:

```
woman(sally).
woman(betty).
man(john).
man(tom).

parent(tom, john).
parent(sally, betty).

sibling(A, B) :-
    parent(C, A),
    parent(C, B),
    A \= B.
```

I have more I'm using for the tree but I don't think they are relevant to this question.

Comment: What is your actual question? Strictly, there is none in your post now. And otherwise yes, some recursive variant of an `ancestor` predicate would likely help you.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I need a recursive function that finds all blood relatives in a family tree.

Comment: :) just update your question, please. It would also help to see what you have so far and what kind of data structures (facts) you are using if you would like to get more specific answers.

Comment: Can you show some attempt at writing a predicate (note: Prolog doesn't have *functions* but *predicates*)? Have you tried anything? If you search stackoverflow.com briefly, you'll find several questions in the prolog area on the topic of family/blood relationships with snippets of code if you're really stuck.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I hope the examples provide some context.

Comment: If you go to the stackoverflow.com search box and enter `[prolog] ancestor` you'll get several hits, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966488/prolog-and-ancestor-relationship