# How to find Relationships between Objects

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, recursion, go

### For People With A Similar Question (written after finding a solution):

This problem, as you might notice according to the answers below, has a lot of different solutions. I only chose Evan's because it was the easiest one for me implement into my own code. However, from what I tried, every other answer also worked. [@SalvadorDali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742297/1090562) linked this [Kaggle page](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-2-word-vectors) which was definitely interesting and I reccomend reading if you are interested. Prolog was also brought up as a possible solution, I'm unfamiliar with it, but if you already know it -- it's probably worth considering. Also, if you just want to get code to use there are working Javascript and Python examples below. However, each one had a different approach to the solution and I'm not sure which is most effecient (feel free to test it yourself).

**For further approaches/reading:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

[Prolog and ancestor relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966488/prolog-and-ancestor-relationship?lq=1)

https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-2-word-vectors

---

Sorry for the confusing title, I can't figure out a way to properly word my question -- any better ideas are welcome.

Because I'm having such a difficult time describing my question, I'll try to explain my goal and code as much as needed:

*Note: my code here is Go, but I'd be happy with answers in other languages as well, if you have any questions I'll try to answer as quick as possible*

Basically, I have an array of "Word" objects that look like this:

```
type Word struct{
     text     string
     synonyms []string
}
```

This is an example of 4 words within the array:

```
  []Word{
      {text: "cat" synonyms: ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"]}
      {text: "kitten" synonyms: ["kitty", "kit"]} 
      {text: "kit" synonyms: ["pack", "bag", "gear"]}
      {text: "computer" synonyms: ["electronics", "PC", "abacus"]}
   }
```

My challenge is writing a method to test for a relationship between 2 words. Of course, testing between 2 words like *"cat"* and *"kitten"* would be easy with the example above. I could just check "Cat"s list of synonyms and test to see if it contains "kitten." With code like this:

```
areWordsRelated(word1 Word, word2 Word) bool{
    for _, elem := range word1.synonyms{
         if elem == word2.text{
             return true
         }
    }
    return false
}
```

**However, I can't figure out how to test for a more distant relationship.**

For example:

```
areWordsRelated("cat","pack") //should return true 
//because "cat" is related to "kitten" which is related to "pack"
areWordsRelated("cat", "computer") //should return false
```

I tried to do it recursively, but all my attempts don't seem to work. Any example code (My code is in Go, but Python, Java, or Javascript are also fine), pseudocode or just explanations would be really great.

Comment: the way you have it built, you'd basically have multiple finite sets of related words (one set would be {computer, electronics, PC, abacus}, another would be {feline, kitten, cat, mouser, bag, gear, pack, etc etc etc}). why not just write code to define all those sets ahead of time, and then test if the two words are both a member of any one set?

Comment: This seems to be a great fit for Prolog

Comment: The code reads in all the Words from a thesaurus, so each word has a different amound of synonyms. Also, it would be ideal if the method could check for relationships between different "distances" so it could find relationships potentially 5 (or more) words apart.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prolog, what benefits would it provide?

Comment: This can easily be done with the tools in Go. All you have to do is recursively apply the transitive property to your collection. I'll be working on a solution during my spare time today.

Comment: Prolog have a declarative syntax to build relations and allow you to query those relations... I'm sorry I can't show you an example because I've learned it some years ago. If no good answer shows up, maybe is worth read about it.

Comment: Here, I have found a related question in Prolog which you could adapt to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966488/prolog-and-ancestor-relationship

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait a bit for other answers in languages I'm more familiar with, but if one doesn't show up I'll try it.

Comment: @DiogoDoreto Progol is a [_declarative_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) language while Go, Python and JavaScript are all [_imperative_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming)... so I wouldn't recommend that solution other than just as a matter of curiosity.

Comment: what would your function return if I will call it with `F('kitty', 'cat')`?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose with my example it would return false. Although ideally it would return true -- if the thesaurus I read from correctly went back and forth. Unfortunately I don't think it did.

Comment: @icza I don't see a different paradigm as a problem if it can solve the problem. As a matter of fact, the solution will be more elegantly represented in Prolog than in any other imperative language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give me some feedback on this I can edit it because it doesn't do exactly what you asked but it is the jist. I'll edit with a technical explanation of what has to be changed to meet your exact example.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    words := []Word{
            {text: "cat", synonyms: []string{"feline", "kitten", "mouser"}},
            {text: "kitten", synonyms: []string{"kitty", "kit"}} ,
            {text: "kit", synonyms: []string{"pack", "bag", "gear"}},
            {text: "computer", synonyms: []string{"electronics", "PC", "abacus"}},
    }

    fmt.Println(areWordsRelated(words, words[0], words[2]))
    fmt.Println(areWordsRelated(words, words[0], words[3]))
}

type Word struct{
     text     string
     synonyms []string
}

func areWordsRelated(words []Word, word1, word2 Word) bool {
    for _, elem := range word1.synonyms{
        if elem == word2.text{
            return true
        } else {
            for _, word := range words {
                if word.text == elem {
                    if (areWordsRelated(words, word, word2)) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

EDIT: This doesn't do quite what you asked because it doesn't make the connection between "pack" and "cat" as pack is not represented by an actual word object and I defined the method to receive word2 as an object (just working off your example). I could instead make that a string so it can check for "pack" in the synonyms array of "kit" before returning but the idea is the same none the less... Here's a high level explanation of the algorithm.

Iterate the synonyms, if it isn't a match, find that `Word` object back in the original collection and call myself with it as the first argument. This will recursively exhaust every path until it finds a match, or there are none left in which case you're outside the loop returning false. The code above runs in go playground and correctly returns `true\nfalse`. Notice that the recursive call is made within an if to protect from returning false prematurely (also a performance enhancement because we return as soon as true is found rather than continue to recurse the paths).

https://play.golang.org/p/gCeY0SthU1

Comment: Is there  a way to make it timeout after being X words away from the starting word? I could just add a parameter to the method keeping track of iterations right?

Comment: @MaximilianSun yeah that would be fairly easy, just add a counter and a check for it in the loop. Return false if you hit the edge limit or whatever you're calling it.

Comment: I think that your note about "pack" not relating to "kit" is mostly a problem on my part with my example rather than your code.

Comment: @MaximilianSun yeah, the example isn't consistent so I just chose to do it that way. If you make `word2` a string instead of a `Word` then modify functions body as needed to compile you'll be able to pass in `words[0]` and "pack" and it will return true

Answer (score 3):

A Python solution:

```
class Word:

   # Dictionary of Words, keyed by name.
   word_dict = {}

   def __init__(self, name, synonyms):
      self.name = name
      self.synonyms = synonyms

      # Update the dictionary.
      Word.word_dict[name] = self
      for s in synonyms:
         if not s in Word.word_dict:
            Word.word_dict[s] = Word(s, [])

   def isAncestor(self, other):
      if other in self.synonyms:
         return True
      for s in self.synonyms:
         if Word.word_dict[s].isAncestor(other):
            return True
      return False

def areWordsRelated(word1, word2):
   if not word1 in Word.word_dict or not word2 in Word.word_dict:
      return False
   return Word.word_dict[word1].isAncestor(word2) or Word.word_dict[word2].isAncestor(word1)

words = []
words.append(Word("cat", ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"]))
words.append(Word("kitten", ["kitty", "kit"]))
words.append(Word("kit", ["patck", "bag", "gear"]))
words.append(Word("computer", ["electronics", "PC", "abacus"]))

print(areWordsRelated("cat", "kit"))
print(areWordsRelated("kit", "cat"))
print(areWordsRelated("cat", "computer"))
print(areWordsRelated("dog", "computer"))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: How would I go about constructing the tree?

Answer (score 3):

First of all it is not clear how do you define relationship here. If your 
"cat" has synonyms: ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"], does that mean that "mouser" has a synonym "cat".

Based on my understanding the answer is no. So here is a solution in python:

```
G = {
    "cat": ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"],
    "kitten": ["kitty", "kit"],
    "kit": ["pack", "bag", "gear"],
    "computer": ["electronics", "PC", "abacus"]
}

def areWordsRelated(G, w1, w2):
    if w1 == w2:
        return True

    frontier = [w1]
    checked = set()
    while len(frontier):
        el = frontier.pop()
        if el in G:
            neighbors = G[el]
            for i in neighbors:
                if i == w2:
                    return True
                if i not in checked:
                    frontier.append(i)
                    checked.add(i)

    return False

areWordsRelated(G, "cat", "pack") #true
areWordsRelated(G, "cat", "computer") #false
```

So what are we doing here? At first you have your graph, which is just dictionary (map in go) which shows your relationship (I basically took your slice).

Our algorithm grows like a mold, maintaining a set of checked elements and a current frontier. If frontier is empty (nothing to explore, then the elements are not connected). We extract one element at a time from a frontier and check all the neighbors. If any of them is the element we are looking for - then there is a connection. Otherwise check if we already have seen such element (and if not than add it to the frontier and to the set of checked).

Notice that if your relationship works in a slightly different way, all you need is to modify a graph.

---

One last word, if you are looking for a normal way to find synonyms take a look at [word to vector algorithm](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-2-word-vectors) and a nice [implementation in python](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/). This will allow you to find really complicated relationship even between words like finding that `California` and `Golden Gate` are related even without having this relationship specified.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample recursive algorithim written in JavaScript, with some jQuery thrown in to make searching the array easier. It probably could be optimized, but should give you something to start with.

```js
$(function() {
  var words = [{
    text: "cat",
    synonyms: ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"]
  }, {
    text: "kitten",
    synonyms: ["kitty", "kit"]
  }, {
    text: "kit",
    synonyms: ["pack", "bag", "gear"]
  }, {
    text: "computer",
    synonyms: ["electronics", "PC", "abacus"]
  }];

  console.log(areWordsRelated('cat', 'pack', words));
  console.log(areWordsRelated('cat', 'rack', words));
});

function areWordsRelated(parentWord, childWord, list) {
  var parentWordItems = $.grep(list, function(element) {
    return element.text === parentWord;
  });

  if (parentWordItems.length === 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    var parentWordItem = parentWordItems[0];
    var remainingItems = $.grep(list, function(element) {
      return element.text !== parentWord;
    });
    if (parentWordItem.synonyms.indexOf(childWord) >= 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < parentWordItem.synonyms.length; i++) {
        var synonym = parentWordItem.synonyms[i];
        if (areWordsRelated(synonym, childWord, remainingItems)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a 2nd degree relationship (as opposed to the 'easy' 1st place example you already know how to find), meaning you have to do one of two things:

(1) The storage-heavy solution requires maintaining a separate list of 2nd-degree relationships and then simply do a search within that (longer) list - this requires maintaining (potentially MUCH) more data about word relationships. For example, if you have 10000 words, and each has roughly 10 synonyms, that's 100,000 first-degree relationships stored. But then you'd have something like a billion 2nd-degree relationships. So of course that gets unwieldy quickly.

In that case, each entry looks like this:
{text: "cat" synonyms: ["feline", "kitten", "mouser"] seconds:["pack",...]}
... and you simply write a separate function that will check for relationships in EITHER 'synonyms' or 'seconds'.

(2) The programmatic solution would be to still only store the 1st-degree relationships and then do an embedded loop.

In this case:

```
//// This checks for 1st degree relationship
areWordsRelated1(word1 Word, word2 Word) bool{
    for _, elem := range word1.synonyms{
         if elem == word2.text{
             return true
         }
    }
    return false
}

//// This checks for 2nd degree by checking 1st and then, if not, 
//// then trying the 1st degree function on the children of word2
//// before giving up and returning false
areWordsRelated2(word1 Word, word2 Word) bool{
    for _, elem1 := range word1.synonyms{
         if elem1 == word2.text{
             return true
         } else {
         for _, elem2 := range elem1.synonyms{
             if areWordsRelated1(word1, elem2) {
                 return true
             }
         }
    }
    return false
}
```

NOTE: I noticed that in your sample data, "cat" was related to "kitten", but "kitten" was not conversely related to "cat".